# Can't make product images clickable

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I've tried many things and many solutions but i can't make product images clickable. Here's the code:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $images .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_catalog' );
}
```

If i make the code look like this, it doesn't show images:

```
return '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' .  get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ) . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
$images .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $images .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_catalog' );
}
$images .= '</a>';
```